# How can I ensure the UPDATE statement in this small LOOP to be executed within a Transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions

I have this loop, which updates @UpdateBlockSize number of records on each iteration:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (@UpdateBlockSize) table1
    SET field1 = nv.value
    FROM table1 i
        INNER JOIN #table2 nv ON nv.id = i.id   
    IF @@ROWCOUNT < @UpdateBlockSize BREAK
END
```

**Question:**
How can I ensure that each iteration works within a transaction so that if it fails, only that iteration is rolled back and the LOOP exits?

Comment: Each update would already be in an implicit transaction. However, if the whole query is called within a transaction, even if you explicitly set transactions within the loop, they will all role back.

Comment: So i f I get a transaction time out, the loop will be exited?

Comment: The query will abort, so essentially yes.

Comment: This is something you can test for yourself (throw an error on a specific iteration and check the results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any single update that fails is it's own transaction (assuming no explicit outer transaction).

If I understand you correctly...

- you want to handle errors gracefully
- you want 10 individual transactions
- if loop number, say, 7 fails, rollback that loop only and exit the loop
- loops 1-6 stay committed

So, try this

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
       UPDATE TOP (@UpdateBlockSize) table1
       SET field1 = nv.value
       FROM table1 i
           INNER JOIN #table2 nv ON nv.id = i.id;
       SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       SET @rc = 0;
    END CATCH
    IF @@ROWCOUNT < @UpdateBlockSize BREAK
END
```

If you want a single transaction for all loops, then don't use a loop. The transaction log will contain all rollback information for all loops because it is a single transaction. Unless this is abbreviated code, a loop adds no value in this case...

Comment: My main concern is transaction time-outs. I imagined, if I run all updates separately within a block (1000 records per transaction) it would not lock the db tables for a long time...

Comment: So maybe I even do not need a loop maybe as it would not help anything?

Comment: @pencilCake: There is no transaction timeout within SQL itself, whether you have one UPDATE or hundreds in a loop. That is, SQL Server can not initiate a timeout when running SQL.

Comment: Then it means if I need to UPDATE 1 million records, I can comfortably run my UPDATE (with JOINS as above sample) without worrying that it may lock the tables involved? My understanding is correct? (No need to update 1000 rows on each iteration)

Comment: @pencilCake: yes, pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the `@@TRANCOUNT` variable - if it > 0 then you have outer transaction, and thus - all of your updates will be committed or rolled back simultaneously. (If you not choose to to commit the outer transaction - that is not recommended).

If = 0 - then each of your loop's UPDATE runs in its own implicit transaction, so - no need to worry then

Try to use this:

```
declare @rc int, @err int 
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (@UpdateBlockSize) table1
    SET field1 = nv.value
    FROM table1 i
        INNER JOIN #table2 nv ON nv.id = i.id   

    SELECT @rc = @@ROWCOUNT, @err = @@ERROR
    IF @rc < @UpdateBlockSize OR @err <> 0 BREAK
END
```

Comment: Oleg, how can I wrap all the UPDATES into an iteration wise transaction? So, if there are gonna be 10 iterations, the updates should be completed by  10 transactions that are run and commited consequently.

Comment: In your case it WILL BE 10 transactions - so, dont worry